# Get author and excerpt from URL

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to be tricky here, I want to show a list of articles with their author and excerpt. I'm using a custom field and want the user to just be able to list the URLs on their own line and that's it.

Is there a way to look up the non-rewritten url based on the friendly one? Then just pull the article ID from there via regex?

Comment: I think this question might be better suited for [wordpress.se].

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about WordPress Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
 url_to_postid('http://wwww.site.com');
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117142/get-author-and-excerpt-from-url/117145?noredirect=1#117145